# Unresolved external errors with LNK2019 error in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new and would be grateful if someone can help me understand what this unresolved externals error is! I get "LNK 1120" and "LNK 2019" when I run the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

inline void sum(int& ac, int n, vector<int> v1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ac = ac + v1.at(i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int N=40;
    int accum = 0;
    vector<int> data(N);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        data.at(i) = i;
    sum(accum, N, data);
    cout << "sum is %d\n" << accum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code looks good to me. Go to the Output tab (should be near the Error List tab down at the bottom of Visual Studio) and copy-paste the build output into the question so we can see exactly what's going wrong

Comment: Maybe you selected the wrong project type and the unresloved external is WinMain() in either case the exact error message should help.

Comment: I just tested this under Visual Studio 2019. It compiled and ran and returned 780 just like ideone: [https://ideone.com/Oxs0Kx](https://ideone.com/Oxs0Kx)

Comment: How do you compile/link your code? Under eclipse it's ok.

Comment: @user4581301  From the output tab, the build output is:
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Test.cpp
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\..[just my folder dir]..\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @Hack06 Using Visual Studio Community 2019!

Comment: @drescher Ah i see.. right so maybe if i just created a new file since everyone seems to be able to run?

Comment: Thanks everyone! Works when I just use a new file.. Though if anyone figures out why the previous didn't work would be curious to know.. Otherwise Thanks!

Comment: Your error definitely means you selected the wrong project type initially. Instead of a console application you choose some type of windows application. You can fix this by changing the subsystem from windows to console. I believe that is a linker setting. Yes its Linker->System->SubSystem

Comment: Consider adding an answer to your own question if you got a solution to it, it may be helpful for someone else later.